# How to resample a pixel to another resolution?

Tags: python

I started coding a mouse track script as a bit of a challenge, where it'll record in any resolution, then convert it all to a single resolution and output an image.

I have it working at a basic level, so it's the equivalent of just stretching everything. For example, if you increase the width and decrease the height of the output, you can still see where the individual pixels were, they're just very wide and squished.

I'm wondering if anyone knows how I'd actually resample the pixels, especially for odd resolutions, so it'd produce less blocky results? As monitors are usually pretty standard resolutions anyway, it's not a huge problem, but it's kinda annoyed me that I've attempted it and couldn't get it working.

I tried getting the remainder of the `width/height_multiply` and adding `value * remainder` to the outside pixels as a way of making them blur if it was a weird scale, but it produced really weird results that were in no way close to what I was wanting.

Here's my current code edited a little:

```
required_res = (3840, 2160)
data = {(1920, 1080: {(0, 2): 52, (1, 2): 549, (6, 3): 125}}

for resolution, coordinates in data.iteritems():

    width_multiply = required_res[0] / resolution[0]
    height_multiply = required_res[1] / resolution[1]

    for coordinate, value in coordinates.iteritems():

        #Figure out new coordinate
        base_coordinate = (int(round(coordinate[0] * width_multiply)),
                           int(round(coordinate[1] * height_multiply)))
        coordinate_list = {base_coordinate: value}


        #Increase pixel size if image is bigger
        if width_multiply_int and height_multiply_int:
            for x in range(-int(width_multiply), int(width_multiply)):
                for y in range(-int(height_multiply), int(height_multiply)):

                    new_coordinate = (base_coordinate[0] + x,
                                      base_coordinate[1] + y)
                    coordinate_list[new_coordinate] = value

        #repeat above bit for "just x" and "just y", it's basically the same


        for c in coordinate_list:
            try:
                new_data[c] = max(new_data[c], value)
            except KeyError:
                new_data[c] = value
```

The value is just so the screen doesn't go totally black. Each new point basically gets a higher number, and it's currently a linear scale from `0 = white` to `latest = black`. [Here's an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlqkJ.jpg) of a day or twos worth of windows usage and a game:

[image]

Edit: I tried the colour suggestion by RuDevel (it doesn't address the problem but I thought it was a cool idea) since it's a little boring when the internet drops for hours at a time. There's less tracks on the picture as I also added a bit where it'd compress down old values, so needed to start a new file.

Didn't turn out quite as well as expected, but as a base point I tried to cycle through the rainbow colours:

[image]

And with them reversed:
[image]

Comment: You can go from subpixels (sampling) all the way down to splines. With a vectorized version of your movements you could - theoretically - reproduce any resolution.

Comment: That's a really nice idea, though it sounds like it'd be difficult to limit the file size. At 60fps that'd be about 10 million points per day, and unless I'm missing something, there'd be no easy way to remove hidden points :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could maybe trace your movements using a pencil that shifts colors over time (e.g. rainbow- style).

That way you'd be able to trace them much longer than with black lines. 
However, I'd still expect you'd have to start a fresh trace image every now and then and thus have constantly growing space- requirements over time.

But if you then converted **only one segment at a time** into a spline, wrote the result to your final output and dropped it immediately you'd need (almost) no extra space for the final conversion.

Another idea would be to *compress* the extracted splines at *significant points* on the fly by noting **position, direction and speed**. That should strongly reduce space- requirements - but defining how to detect such a significant point might be hard.

One method for that might be to define an area (e.g. center area of a `5x5 grid`) to be something like 'the **center of mass**'. A segment would be noted *once* when it passes through that center or (for outer lines) at the nearest point towards the center. You'd however need to define some type of 'physics' to reproduce (something comparable to) the original image.

As mentioned **upsampling** the subpixels of your image should work as well, but your type of Image would - most probably (*by it's very nature*) - leave very few distinct edge directions for the reproduction.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, the colours is a cool idea, I'll try figure out the formula to map a selection of colours to a range (I guess currently it's just white to black). Could you clarify what you mean by convert one segment at a time to a spline, write then drop it? I got the idea from your original comment of storing the list of points with its start time (to allow multiple resolutions), then draw it backwards in 4k resolution or something to remove lines that were totally hidden by other pixels, but again I realised the space requirements would be huge haha.

Comment: With the grid idea, in terms of where the lines pass over edges, I did initially think that would be a great idea, but then I realised, just say you scaled 1080 to 4k, there'd be a very noticeable grid of pixel, no pixel, pixel, etc. I don't quite understand the center of mass idea though haha.

Comment: The net dropped on me as I tried to edit the comment haha. I was going to say I've added in a bit to compress the old values down and stop the counter from getting too high, which should help a lot with keeping it readable. It's not something that can be tested quickly though so I'll be playing with the values over the next few days :)

Comment: @Peter well- in order to vectorize your curves you might want to calculate spline- segments. If you converted all into splines and stored all those values you would still require huge space on disk- but you could re-sample to any resolution you'd like. If you just calculated one single spline, output that to your destination file and did NOT save it's values you'd end up with an image of your wished resolution without the need to store all splines or even have all splines in memory.

Comment: I think I may get you now, what you're suggesting is to output straight to the resolution instead of doing all the calculations later? That'd never actually crossed my mind and is a decent idea, however yesterday I kinda figured how I could resample individual pixels (I got the maths wrong before), so I'll also give that a shot again too